# Dataframe insert Column with unique ID inside a <input>

Tags: python, html, dataframe, range

I have a Dataframe and i want to add a new column to it with an unique ID.

This works perfectly fine:

```
df.insert(0,'A',range(1, 1 + len(df)))
```

The problem is, that i need to add a Checkbox and assign the ID to the name of the Checkbox.
I tried:

```
df.insert(0,'A','<input name=' + str(range(1, 1 + len(df))) + ' type="checkbox">')
```

The code is not executet so my HTML shows the following:

```
<input name="range(1", 103)="" type="checkbox">
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Turning it into a string means it's no longer an iterator.  You just need to make it an iterator:

```
df.insert(0,'A',['<input name="{}" type="checkbox">'.format(i+1) for i in range(len(df))])
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Works perfect !